# Fusion table API, INSERT query, bad request

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with fields: username, description,latitude,longitud,geolocation. I am trying to create a new row with information via the google API. I triple checked that the fusion table is open, the tableid and the apikey are correct, and I have the fusiontable API enabled with 0% of the quota. I think the wrong request must be because some coma or quotation mark but to be honest it completely escapes me. I have tried different combinations and cannot find the mistake. Below error that I get, the code that use in php to generate the link and the link itself. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

link returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Php Code:

```
$apikey = "AIzaSyB4BMlrZIlJB-Apo8t_dO9K18uL8O2s5TA";
$tableid = "1X0rFoG7Tt2Ocm2rE39wPuamZCrFiS4D32Odgbh03";
$username="webuser";
$description="nujkn";
$latitude="78";
$longitud="110";
$geolocation="98.8789, 150.1111";

$link = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT+INTO+".$tableid."+(username,description,latitude,longitud,geolocation)+VALUES+('".$username."','".$description."','".$latitude."','".$longitud."','".$geolocation."')&key={".$apikey."}";
```

Link generated: https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT+INTO+1X0rFoG7Tt2Ocm2rE39wPuamZCrFiS4D32Odgbh03+(username,description,latitude,longitud,geolocation)+VALUES+('webuser','nujkn','78','110','98.8789')&key={AIzaSyB4BMlrZIlJB-Apo8t_dO9K18uL8O2s5TA}

which in browser looks like: https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT+INTO+1X0rFoG7Tt2Ocm2rE39wPuamZCrFiS4D32Odgbh03+(username,description,latitude,longitud,geolocation)+VALUES+(%27webuser%27,%27nujkn%27,%2778%27,%27110%27,%2798.8789%27)&key={AIzaSyB4BMlrZIlJB-Apo8t_dO9K18uL8O2s5TA}

Comment: `INSERT`  requires: 1. [**Authentication via OAuth**](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) 2. [**the POST-method**](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#CreatingColumn)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr. Molle, I thought  that you could still do  SQL inserts into Fusiontables with the  API key if table was open, it is absolutely necessary to get the Oauth authentication? (it would add quite a lot of since basically it just an insert a row from a PHP serverside when a user wants to add info, don't want to have users needing to login with their Google credentials)

Comment: The users don't need to login, see [**offline access**](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

Comment: To clarify why you need OAuth: you've posted your API-key, when write-access would be possible by providing the key everybody could do whatever he wants to(DELETE,UPDATE,CREATE etc.) by using your API-key(IP-restrictions  are not secure, because IP's may be shared across hosts). The API-key is only used to identify your project(e.g. for quota-usage and check for enabled API ), but will not give permissions for the queries(when the table would be private even a SELECT would fail).